# Is category equivalence unique up to isomorphism?

Tags: category-theory

Let  $\mathbf C$, $\mathbf D$ be categories and $F, F':\mathbf C \to \mathbf D$ and $G, G':\mathbf D \to \mathbf C$ be functors of the shown direction.  Is it the case that, if each of $(F,G)$ and $(F',G')$ is an equivalence, then $F\cong F'$ (isomorphic in $\mathbf D^\mathbf C$)?

Initially I thought (without thinking) that there couldn't be more than "one" equivalence (up to isomorphism) between two categories.  But, once I tried to prove this, I couldn't find any  reason whay it should be so.  Was I wrong?  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: There being multiple equivalences is what give categories symmetry.

Answer (score 12):

No; for instance, let $C = D = 2$, the discrete category with two objects, and let $F = G = \mathrm{id}_C$ while $F' = G'$ is the functor exchanging the objects.

Edit to add some more simple examples:

If we think of the poset $(\mathbb Z, <)$ as a category, then the two equivalences $\mathrm{id}_{\mathbb Z}: \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ and $S: \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ are not isomorphic.

If we think of a group as a one-object category (so that functors correspond to group homomorphisms), then for any non-trivial group $G$ the mapping $G \times G \to G \times G$ which swaps the elements is not isomorphic to the identity on $G \times G$. More generally, two group homomorphisms are isomorphic if and only if they are conjugate, so in particular any non-identity automorphism of an abelian group (e.g. negation for most abelian groups) is not isomorphic to the identity on that group.

Comment: In this counter-example, is it meant that each of (F, F') and (G, G') forms an equivalence, and that there is no natural isomorphism between F and G?  If so (and if I understand "the discrete category with two objects" correctly), I think I see that (F, F') and (G, G') each forms an equivalence, but I cannot see how F and G fail to be isomorphic.  If (F, G) and (F', G') are meant to form equivalences, I cannot see how F and F' fail to be isomorphic, given F = F'.  I'm sure I misunderstand something terribly. More detailed help for an inexperienced learner is appreciated. (I study more, too.)

Comment: My bad, I changed notation from your question. It has been fixed now. Now the notation in my answer matches that in your question. We have that $(F,G)$ and $(F',G')$ are equivalences, yet $F$ and $F'$ are not isomorphic. To see this, write $a,b$ for the two objects of $2$. An isomorphism $\chi$ between $F$ and $F'$ would in particular give an arrow $\chi_a : F(a) \to F'(a)$, or in other words, $\chi_a: a \to b$, which obviously does not exist.

Answer (score 7):

To get some more intuition on this, note that analogous statements aren't true for other mathematical objects. For example if $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic groups then the set of isomorphisms between them is in bijection with the set of automorphisms of either of them. A group can have more than one distinct automorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Peter Freyd's book "Abelian Categories" contains a discussion of this topic in Exercise B at the end of Chapter 1. He defines the automorphism class group of a category $C$ to be the group of equivalences $C\to C$ modulo those naturally isomorphic to the identity.  As an example where this is non-trivial, he gives the category of ordered sets and order-preserving functions.  The functor that reverses the ordering is an equivalence but is not isomorphic to the identity.